# Motivation for Ionescu-Tulcea extension theorem (as opposed to Kolmogorov's)

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I recently asked a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/436999/496689) on the differences between Ionescu-Tulcea and Kolmogorov extension theorems (ITET and KET for short). A lot of my confusion has been cleared there and what I understood from the discussion in the comments may be summarized as follows:

1. Despite the fact that most books state ITET for the cases where the index set is either $\mathbb{N}$ or even $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, there is in fact a version of it, which doesn't assume the countability of the index set.
2. These general ITET-type theorems start with a consistent family of measures *(exactly like KET)* and assume that they are linked with each other by regular transition kernels.
3. General versions of KET also start with a consistent family of measures, but impose some quasi-topological assumption on the state space
4. KET-type theorems typically follow from ITET-type ones, because the quasi-topological assumptions of KET are there precisely to ensure the existence of regular transition kernels

What I still do not understand, is **why would one want to use ITET instead of KET**?

I can think of one obvious reason:

- If the index set is just $\mathbb{N}$, one can build the consistent family from a chain of kernels. In other words, one can start with a chain of kernels and obtain consistency as a by-product of $\mathbb{N}$-ITET. Neat!

However, if the index set is not $\mathbb{N}$, one cannot build the consistent family of measures by chaining kernels, so it is necessary to obtain consistency from somewhere else.

It seems that the above leaves two possible reasons to prefer ITET to KET:

1. KET's (quasi-)topological assumptions turn out to be too restrictive for one's needs.
2. ITET's assumptions are sometimes easier to check.

The first one seems rather plausible to me, but I don't know of an example. Regarding the second, I cannot even imagine why checking ITET's assumptions may be easier than checking the KET's assumptions.

---

So, my questions are these:

1. Why would one prefer ITET to KET? How this situation could look?
2. Are there any "practical" (whatever that means) examples of when KET's assumptions (even in their stronger forms, such as, the space being Polish) fail, but ITET's don't?

---

**P.S.** Browsing Google Scholar for answers, I stumbled upon the following remark in the book *Handbook of Markov Decision Processes: Methods and Applications* by Eugene A. Feinberg, Adam Shwartz (page 8):
[image: page 8]
Do the authors mean less powerful versions of KET or they really need ITET instead?

Comment: For Q2: Examples of non-perfect probability spaces are non-constructive --- they need the axiom of choice or some such.  So in that sense there is no "practical" example in which perfectness fails.

Comment: For P.S.: Yes, the authors mean a less powerful version of KET. A general version of KET only assumes that the probability spaces are perfect.

Comment: ITET does not require separability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite right to state that ITET-type theorems start *exactly like KET*. Unlike KET, ITET starts with a consistent family of transition kernels. And that leads to the answer for question 1.

Q1: One would (or at least could) prefer to appeal to an ITET when one is given a random process by means of transition kernels. A typical example is a random walk with the index set $\{0,1,2,...\}$, which is usually defined by transition probabilities, not by joint distributions. Then ITET may be invoked directly, and there is no need to deal with topological assumptions.

Q2: Whatever "practical" means, a practical example should be at least constructible or definable. A general KET assumes the underlying measure spaces are perfect. So an example where KET assumptions fail would have to be non-perfect. But to show the existence of non-perfect probability spaces one needs a form of the axiom of choice. So in that sense there is no such "practical" example.

Comment: In the [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/DCF12E254694F751A0A116C957181A20/S0008439500004781a.pdf/comparison_of_methods_for_constructing_probability_measures_on_infinite_product_spaces.pdf) which Michael Greinecker cited in the comments of my previous question ITET in the form of Theorem 1 starts exactly with a consistent family of probability measures.

Comment: Please, see also the P.S. I added to the question.

Comment: @tsnao The main difference in assumptions is that ITET assumes a consistent family of measures *given by transition kernels* (or a consistent family of transition kernels). KET does not assume that.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I was trying to say essentially the same thing. That is, that ITET assumes a consistent family of measures _compatible_ with a family of transition kernels. But yes, those are more or less the same thing, I just misunderstood what you said.